# Lorentz force experienced by outer electrons

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

So we have a spray of electrons with charge density $\rho$, radius $a$ and it's moving at velocity $v$. I need to show the outer edge electrons are experiencing the following force

$$F=\frac{e \lambda}{2 \pi a \epsilon_0}(1-\frac{v²}{c²}).$$

Where $\lambda=e/l$ ($l$ is the length). So far using Lorentz's force equation $F=eE + evB$ and following theorems $$B=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2 \pi a},$$ $$E=\frac{e}{4 \pi \epsilon_0},$$ $$\rho =e/V=e/ \pi a² l,$$ $$j=I/A=I/\pi a²=v \rho.$$

I've found out that $$\frac{el \lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 a²}+\frac{2ea \lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 a²}\cdot\frac{v²}{c²},$$

but I have no idea where I can get a minus sign or how to get rid of that $l$.

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate a force, and not a force per unit length?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that I need to calculate a force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While evaluating the second term, i.e. force due to magnetic field, there are some mistakes, firstly $e$ needs to be written with it's appropriate sign. Therefore we have $F_b=-evB$. Proceeding thus you shall get $\frac{e}{2\pi a\epsilon_0}.\frac{v^2}{c^2}.\frac{e}{l}$.  You can then replace $\frac{e}{l}$ with $\lambda$. Ultimately $F_b$ should be $-\frac{e\lambda v^2}{2\pi a\epsilon_0 c^2}$ . I hope i helped you.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but I still don't know how to get rid of $l$ and how to get same denominator for the Coloumb force.